# Select values from an array by array of keys

Tags: php, arrays, subset, array-key

I have two arrays of the same length containing some values.

```
$a = array("a","b","x","x");
$b = array("f","g","g","h");
```

Now I want to get the values from `$b` at the index postions from where `$a` is `x`.

```
 $ids = array_keys($a, 'x');
 $res = ???($b,$ids);
 print_r($res);
```

So what function will give me an Array containing `g` and `h`. Or is there even a more elegent (e.g. not using `array_keys()`) to do this?

Comment: faster way? your current code runs slow?

Comment: Sorry. I ment it in the aspect of more elegant.

Comment: `array_intersect_key($b, preg_grep('/^x$/D', $a))`  (Using regex is clearly, always, the more elegant solution. \*grin\*)

Answer (score 1):

```
$needle = 'x';
$res    = array();
foreach($a as $key => $value) {
    if ($value == $needle) {
        $res[] = $b[$key];
    }
}
```